# A coin toss problem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I am carrying out some self-study relating to mixed random variables and I ran into a problem that requires one to show that

$$b^{m+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{m+k}{m}a^k + a^{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\binom{n+k}{n} b^k = 1,$$ if $a,b> 0$ and $a+b=1.$

I have tested that the equality holds for different combinations of $n,m$ between 1 and 4. For this range of values, it appears $$b^{m+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{m+k}{m}a^k + a^{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\binom{n+k}{n} b^k =(a+b)^{\min(n,m)} = 1.$$

I do not know how to provide a rigorous proof of this assertion. Can someone please set me on the right path?

Comment: For your second equation, do we still have $a+b = 1$? If no, it doesn't make sense as the powers are unbalanced.

Comment: @CalvinLin yes indeed, we need $a+b=1$. I'll effect that in the question shortly.

Comment: I recommend to add the tag probability and/or combinatorics

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24b%5E%7Bm%2B1%7D%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%5Cbinom%7Bm%2Bk%7D%7Bm%7Da%5Ek%2Ba%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5Em%5Cbinom%7Bn%2Bk%7D%7Bn%7D%20b%5Ek%3D1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%3D1%24&p=1), there's several AoPS threads, e.g., [Combinatorics](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1366908p7512797), [Binomial coefficient problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1320666p7114569) ...

Comment: (cont). (with this stating it's problem $7$ of the IMO shortlist $1975$, and linking to [For every x,y such that x+y=1 prove the sum is equal to 1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h367915)), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Set Up**

The whole problem almost tell us explicitly to treat $a$ and $b=1-a$ as probabilities, so let's do that. Say you toss a coin and have probability $a$ to get head and $b$ to get tail. Toss the coin $n+m+1$ times.

**First Term of LHS**

The probability that you get $m+1$ tails after tossing the coin $m+k+1$ times is given by the summand of the first LHS term:

$$
\binom{m+k}{m}a^{k}b^{m+1}
$$

Therefore, the first sum can be interpreted as the probability to toss at least $m+1$ tails:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{m+k}{m}a^{k}b^{m+1}
$$

**Second Term of LHS**

Similarly, the probability that you get $n+1$ heads after tossing the coin $n+k+1$ times is given by the summand of the second LHS term:

$$
\binom{n+k}{n}a^{n+1}b^{k}
$$

Therefore, the second sum can be interpreted as the probability to toss at least $n+1$ heads:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n+k}{n}a^{n+1}b^{k}
$$

**Putting It All Together**

The LHS is then the sum of probability of tossing at least $n+1$ tails and at least $m+1$ heads. If that does not ring a bell, at least $m+1$ heads means at most $n$ tails. So the LHS is the probability of tossing at least $n+1$ tails or at most $n$ tails, which is, of course one.

Answer (score 1):

We get for the first term on the LHS that it is

$$b^{m+1} [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{k\ge 0} {m+k\choose m} a^k z^k
= b^{m+1} [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-az)^{m+1}}.$$

This is

$$(-1)^{m+1} \frac{b^{m+1}}{a^{m+1}} \; \underset{z}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(z-1/a)^{m+1}}.$$

Now residues sum to zero and the residue at infinity is zero by
inspection. We may use minus the residues at $z=1$ and $z=1/a.$ We have
for the former

$$(-1)^{m+1} \frac{b^{m+1}}{a^{m+1}} \frac{1}{(1-1/a)^{m+1}} = 1.$$

We get for the latter using the Leibniz rule

$$- \frac{1}{m!} \left( \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z} \right)^{(m)}
\\ = - \frac{1}{m!} \sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k}
\frac{(-1)^k }{z^{n+1+k}} (n+1)^{\overline{k}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{m-k+1}} 1^{\overline{m-k}}
\\ = - \frac{1}{m!} \sum_{k=0}^m {m\choose k}
\frac{(-1)^k }{z^{n+1+k}} {n+k\choose k} k!
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{m-k+1}} (m-k)!
\\ = - \sum_{k=0}^m
\frac{(-1)^k }{z^{n+1+k}} {n+k\choose k} 
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{m-k+1}}.$$

Put $z=1/a$ and restore the scalar in front to obtain

$$- (-1)^{m+1} \frac{b^{m+1}}{a^{m+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^m a^{n+1+k} (-1)^k {n+k\choose n}
\frac{1}{(1-1/a)^{m-k+1}}
\\ = - \frac{b^{m+1}}{a^{m+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^m a^{n+1+k} {n+k\choose n}
\frac{1}{(1/a-1)^{m-k+1}}
\\ = - b^{m+1} a^{n+1}
\sum_{k=0}^m {n+k\choose n} \frac{1}{(1-a)^{m-k+1}}
\\ = - a^{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^m {n+k\choose n} b^k.$$

This is the claim.